# Trouble with getArgs in old Haskell code

Tags: haskell

I am having trouble with compiling a Haskell program that was written
some years ago for an earlier version of the Glasgow Haskell Compiler.

It had the following four lines, about which the current compiler complains.

```
import Monad
import List
import IO
import System
```

I replaced the first three, after looking at the library documentation, with:

```
import Control.Monad
import Data.List
import System.IO
```

But the last one is giving me trouble.  If I run the compiler with these three
lines instead of the previous four, I get an error message relating to getArgs

cnf1.hs:657:13: Not in scope: `getArgs'

I have found getArgs in the library docs but it seems that it is not available 
by default, and I have to somehow (how??) use the legacy haskell98-2.0.0.1

How do I persuade the compiler to look in the haskell98 place for getArgs,
or what is the currently accepted way of doing the same thing as getArgs.

FWIW, I'm a rank amateur in Haskell. I'm much more at home with C & C++.

Answer (score 20):

[`getArgs`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/System-Environment.html#v:getArgs) has been moved to [`System.Environment`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/System-Environment.html). Import that, and you should be fine.

By the way, you can use [Hoogle](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=getArgs) to find where functions are.

Comment: Thanks, I found it in System.Environment. Solved.